# Using android-Asynctask to connect but still getting error

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to connetc to a URL so that i can use my PHP file to do a POST. My android app keeps crashing and i keep getting an error when i execute this line of code:

OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

Here is my code and below it is the error i get in android studio. Thank You.

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://www.cs.csub.edu/~zobeid/Android/login.php";
        if(type.equals("login")) {
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

> FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>                                                                                               Process: com.example.modernkill_laptop.mysqlproject, PID: 18789
>                                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

Comment: Which error do you get you think?

Comment: @greenapps i get an error right when i do this.

OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();


at com.example.modernkill_laptop.mysqlproject.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:60)
                                                                                                at com.example.modernkill_laptop.mysqlproject.BackgroundWorker.doInBackground(BackgroundWorker.java:42)

Comment: just suggesting, that you better to use network library such as okhttp, retrofit, etc which is easier to use than manual HttpUrlConnection

Comment: quick guess: does the AndroidManifest.xml file specify that the app needs the internet permission (<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />) ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys so i found a solution to my problem and its just the way that i am trying to connect everything. So for anyone who is trying to connect to a PHPMySQL Database follow this quick and easy tutorial located her. Solved all my issues and problems.

http://androidcss.com/android/android-php-mysql-login-tutorial/